# Overloading Pre-Increment Operator

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, operators, overloading

Here is the declaration:

```
 Iterator operator++();//pre-increment
```

Here is the definition:

```
LinkedList::Iterator& LinkedList::Iterator::operator++(){
   return Iterator(current->next);//this is giving me an error
}
```

Here is how the class looks

```
class LinkedList{
public:
    Node struct{
      /*contains pointer to next node and an integer value*/
      int val;
      Node* next;
    };
    class Iterator{
    public:
      Iterator& operator++();//pre-increment
    protected:
      Node* current;//points to current node
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [This operator overloading canonical implementation reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations) might be helpful. Especially the section about the increment and decrement operators. By the way, and to be honest, any decent text-book or tutorial should have shown you the correct way. It also helps to think logically about it: What does the increment and decrement operators modify?

Comment: The implementation doesn't make much sense. Increment operator is normally expected to have a side effect of modifying the object it's called on; but yours does not. In fact, I don't think it even compiles - it tries to return a temporary by reference.

Comment: You are right about it being temporary, which I tried to fix, but then I am returning a local value if I try to make an iterator object. I get a warning for that instead,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a *new* iterator object, and (attempt to) return a reference to that.

The prefix-increment operator modifies **`this`** object, and should return a reference to itself:

```
current = current->next;  // TODO: Add checking for not going out of bounds or dereferencing a null pointer
return *this;
```

Comment: TODO is optional BTW, `auto it = std::end(my_vector); ++it;` is UB.